# Functional object-oriented programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Following the book ["Get programming with Haskell"](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/get-programming-with-haskell) I stumbled over rather confusing exercise. One of the chapters explains how to make simple objects using closures. So, for instance we have a tuple which describes a primitive robot:
`(name, attack, hp)`. And using this tuple we can construct a robot like this:

```
robot (name,attack,hp)  = \message -> message (name,attack,hp)
```

for instance:

```
killerRobot = robot ("Kill3r", 25, 200)
```

And so on, the author explains how to make accessor functions using this structure:

```
hp (_,_,hp) = hp
attack (_,a,_) = a

getHP aRobot = aRobot hp
getAttack aRobot = aRobot attack
```

so we can examine how many hit point the certain robot has:

```
getHP killerRobot
```

So far so good and I'm not going to rewrite the entire chapter, but I can't catch one further thing. Next we have a function:

```
damage aRobot attackDamage = aRobot (\(n,a,h) ->
                                      robot (n,a,h-attackDamage))
```

and another function

```
fight aRobot defender = damage defender attack
  where attack = if getHP aRobot > 10
                 then getAttack aRobot
                 else 0
```

which emulates a combat between two robots.
So we can write something like that:

```
gentleGiant = robot ("Mr. Friendly", 10, 300)
gentleGiantRound1 = fight killerRobot gentleGiant
killerRobotRound1 = fight gentleGiant killerRobot
gentleGiantRound2 = fight killerRobotRound1 gentleGiantRound1
killerRobotRound2 = fight gentleGiantRound1 killerRobotRound1
gentleGiantRound3 = fight killerRobotRound2 gentleGiantRound2
killerRobotRound3 = fight gentleGiantRound2 killerRobotRound2
```

and it works just fine. But when I try to put this into a function, which incapsulates these steps and returns the result of the last step (actually the task is slightly different) I get a whole bunch of errors related to type system I guess. I'll show a simplified version which throws errors:

```
roundFights rb1 rb2 = 
 let rb2' = fight rb1 rb2
 in fight rb2' rb1
```

The second fight makes compiler explode with errors. All those functions don't have type signatures intentionally - the same thing inside the book - because it's just one of the introductory chapters and type signatures have not yet explained.

Can someone suggest what's wrong?

Here is the source code:

```
robot (name, attack, hp) = \message -> message (name, attack, hp)

name (nm, _, _) = nm
attack (_, a, _) = a
hp (_, _, p) = p

getName r = r name
getAttack r = r attack
getHP r = r hp

setName r nm = r $ \(_, a, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp)
setAttack r a = r $ \(nm, _, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp)
setHP r hp = r $ \(nm, a, _) -> robot (nm, a, hp)

printRobot r = r $ \(nm, a, hp) -> nm ++ " attack:" ++ show a ++ " hp:" ++ show hp

damage r ad = r $ \(nm, a, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp - ad)
fight atacker defender = damage defender power where
  power = if getHP atacker > 10
          then getAttack atacker
          else 0

lives = map getHP

roundFights rb1 rb2 = 
   let rb2' = fight rb1 rb2
   in fight rb2' rb1
     

rb1 = robot("Killer", 25, 200)
rb2 = robot("Slayer", 15, 200)
```

and the errors sheet I get:

```
D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:27:18:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t8 ~ ((t7, t8, t8) -> t0) -> t0
    Expected type: ((t7, t8, t8) -> ((t7, t8, t8) -> t0) -> t0) -> t6
      Actual type: ((t7, t8, t8) -> t8) -> t6
    Relevant bindings include
      rb2' :: ((t4, t5, t5) -> t5) -> t8
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:26:8)
      rb2 :: ((t2, t3, t6) -> ((t2, t3, t6) -> t) -> t)
             -> ((t4, t5, t5) -> t5) -> t8
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:25:17)
      rb1 :: ((t7, t8, t8) -> t8) -> t6
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:25:13)
      roundFights :: (((t7, t8, t8) -> t8) -> t6)
                     -> (((t2, t3, t6) -> ((t2, t3, t6) -> t) -> t)
                         -> ((t4, t5, t5) -> t5) -> t8)
                     -> t6
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:25:1)
    In the second argument of `fight', namely `rb1'
    In the expression: fight rb2' rb1

D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:30:27:
    No instance for (Num t1) arising from the literal `200'
    The type variable `t1' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rb1 :: (([Char], t1, t1) -> t) -> t
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:30:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 200
    In the first argument of `robot', namely `("Killer", 25, 200)'
    In the expression: robot ("Killer", 25, 200)

D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:31:27:
    No instance for (Num t1) arising from the literal `200'
    The type variable `t1' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rb2 :: (([Char], t1, t1) -> t) -> t
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:31:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 200
    In the first argument of `robot', namely `("Slayer", 15, 200)'
    In the expression: robot ("Slayer", 15, 200)

D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:33:8:
    No instance for (Ord t1) arising from a use of `fight'
    The type variable `t1' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rb2' :: (([Char], t1, t1) -> t) -> t
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:33:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Ord (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Ord () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      ...plus 24 others
    In the expression: fight rb1 rb2
    In an equation for rb2': rb2' = fight rb1 rb2

D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:34:8:
    No instance for (Ord t1) arising from a use of `fight'
    The type variable `t1' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rb1' :: (([Char], t1, t1) -> t) -> t
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Ord (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Ord () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      ...plus 24 others
    In the expression: fight rb2' rb1
    In an equation for rb1': rb1' = fight rb2' rb1

D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:35:9:
    No instance for (Ord t1) arising from a use of `fight'
    The type variable `t1' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      rb2'' :: (([Char], t1, t1) -> t) -> t
        (bound at D:\Dropbox\Documents\Work\HS\GetProg\Unit 10\Robot.hs:35:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Ord (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Ord () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      ...plus 24 others
    In the expression: fight rb1' rb2'
    In an equation for rb2'': rb2'' = fight rb1' rb2' Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Can you paste the errors you get?

Comment: Sure, I've just added them

Comment: The error messages do not match the code you posted (for example, the errors mention `rb1'` and `rb2''`, but they're nowhere in your code). Are you sure you have posted your actual code? Perhaps you have omitted some parts?

Comment: Source code is also included..

Comment: I still don't see any mentions of `rb1'` or `rb2''`

Comment: I meant if I tried to fight rb1 and rb1 with each other (using the results of the previous fight in the next fight) a couple of times outside the function - everything would be OK,

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin OK. If I comment out those definitions of rb1 and rb2 it still doesn't compile with an error about the infinite types (the first one).

Comment: I guess there's a problem with your `damage` function, but I haven't figured out why (it's making me mad without types :P). You can try this definition instead: `damage aRobot attackDamage = robot (getName aRobot, getAttack aRobot, getHP aRobot - attackDamage)` and it should work.

Comment: I'll try, but I took all the definitions from the book :) And the `damage` function works good if you try it by itself, Actually the task is (literaly): _...Write a threeRoundFight function that takes two robots and has them fight for three rounds, returning the winner. To avoid having so many different variables for robot state, use a series of nested lambda functions so you can just overwrite robotA and robotB._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code works fine in an untyped setting (say, Scheme or JavaScript).

In a typed setting it could work, but only if it involves fairly complex types, namely rank-2 types. The type inference engine can not infer those, which must be annotated manually.

To stress the point, let's try to use rank-1 types, only, adding all the annotations. This part compiles fine.

```
type Robot a = ((String, Int, Int) -> a) -> a

robot :: (String, Int, Int) -> Robot a
robot (name, attack, hp) = \message -> message (name, attack, hp)

name :: (String, Int, Int) -> String
name (nm, _, _) = nm
attack :: (String, Int, Int) -> Int
attack (_, a, _) = a
hp :: (String, Int, Int) -> Int
hp (_, _, p) = p

getName :: Robot String -> String
getName r = r name
getAttack :: Robot Int -> Int
getAttack r = r attack
getHP :: Robot Int -> Int
getHP r = r hp

setName :: Robot (Robot a) -> String -> Robot a
setName r nm = r $ \(_, a, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp)
setAttack :: Robot (Robot a) -> Int -> Robot a
setAttack r a = r $ \(nm, _, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp)
setHP :: Robot (Robot a) -> Int -> Robot a
setHP r hp = r $ \(nm, a, _) -> robot (nm, a, hp)

printRobot :: Robot String -> String
printRobot r = r $ \(nm, a, hp) -> nm ++ " attack:" ++ show a ++ " hp:" ++ show hp

damage :: Robot (Robot a) -> Int -> Robot a
damage r ad = r $ \(nm, a, hp) -> robot (nm, a, hp - ad)

fight :: Robot Int -> Robot (Robot a) -> Robot a
fight atacker defender = damage defender power where
  power = if getHP atacker > 10
          then getAttack atacker
          else 0
```

Above, a `Robot a` indicates a robot value which can only be used to compute values of type `a`. E.g. from a `Robot Int` you can extract the attack and HP, but not the name.

Looking at the code... a lot of weird types arise! The type of `fight` is very puzzling:

```
fight :: Robot Int -> Robot (Robot a) -> Robot a
```

The first robot must produce its attack, so it is a `Robot Int`, while the second one must fight and produce a `Robot a`, hence the weird type `Robot (Robot a)`.

From this, we get that we can't hope to type both `fight r1 r2` and `fight r2 r1`: that would require `Int = Robot a`, which is impossible.

```
  • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘((String, Int, Int) -> a) -> a’
      Expected type: Robot (Robot a)
        Actual type: Robot Int
```

What could be the solution? Use rank-2 robots:

```
newtype Robot = Robot (forall a. ((String, Int, Int) -> a) -> a)
```

The `forall a` here indicates that a rank-2 robot can generate *any* result we choose, not just a single one. Hence, from a rank-2 robot we can extract both name and HP.

We need to wrap/unwrap everything using the constructor, which can be a bit annoying:

```
robot :: (String, Int, Int) -> Robot
robot (name, attack, hp) = Robot (\message -> message (name, attack, hp))
getName :: Robot -> String
getName (Robot r) = r name
-- etc.
```

Now, `fight` should work. I'll leave the rest for the OP to try.

Note that theoretical results (Yoneda's lemma) state that the polymorphic type we used, `forall a. ((String, Int, Int) -> a) -> a` is isomorphic to `(String, Int, Int)`, so we indeed we have reinvented tuples in a more complicated way.

Concluding: I am a bit surprised that a Haskell book suggested this approach. It seems quite advanced material to me. I wonder what the intended solution was.

Comment: Brilliant! It really helped. Still it doesn't explain the author's general idea of using this type of language constructions without any explanation. Initally a used that type synonyms: `type RTuple = (String, Int, Int)
type Robot a = (RTuple -> a) -> a`, but they didn't help me because I didn't use this idea of `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}`. Thnak you.

Comment: In my opinion, there's no advantage here. I have no idea about why the book suggests this. It could be a nice exercise for its own sake, since it forces you to use a lot of functions / continuations. But continuation passing style is known to make things much harder, and is only worth it when you need something like `callCC` or some other "early exit" mechanism. I would not consider suggesting this to a beginner.